# Colorizing russian map with leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'd like to colorize russian map with leaflet.But there is a problem with a region (Chukotka Autonomous Okrug), that is placed on the "bend" line of the map. Part of the region appears on the other part of the map (here's a link to the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQSlG.png). I've already tried to use noWrap option, but it didn't help. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide a link to your GeoJSON collection?

Comment: @iH8 Thank you for your answer. A link for GeoJSON [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aaa82abe52fb405080d4). It's quite big though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when you cross the international dataline. What you want can be done but you've got to edit your geometries. In your case you would need to add 360 to every coordinate you encounter that's left of the prime meridian, thus every negative longitude. Mapbox has a nice example on the matter:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/cross-date-line/